# Playing a youtube video's audio part only in Android MediaPlayer

Tags: android, media-player

I want to play youtube videos in my application.I get this data from gdata.youtube.com with a xml.Is there a more suitable way to do this?

Also i want to play only audio part of a youtube video.I don't want to show video view.Is it possible in MediaPlayer component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attempting to do this is in violation of YouTube's [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms) (Section II, item 10 and item 14 stops you from creating tiny, unnoticeable player windows)